# Query Custom Posts - Add To Selection

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, metabox

Which I have working, but not correctly. When I add this metabox to my page it messes up the permalink to always display the slug of one of the organization post types. When I remove this metabox the post is named correctly (as the title is). If there a different or better way to query posts outside the loop?

What I'm trying to do is query all the organizations in my post type and display them in a selection list for the user to choose from.

This is what seems to be messing up my permalink.

```
function show_custom_meta_box_org() {
    global $post; 
    $org = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'organizations', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="orglist_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // get value of this field if it exists for this post
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_orglist', true);

    ?>
    <table class="form-table" id="orgList">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="selectorg" name="_orglist">
                    <option value="">Select Organization</option>
                <?php while($org->have_posts()) : $org->the_post(); ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp_reset_postdata();` to restore the global $post variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using new WP_Query. It restores the $post variable to the current post in the main query.

call `wp_reset_postdata();` after `endwhile;`

```
<?php while($org->have_posts()) : $org->the_post(); ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endwhile;
// reset main query
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to do anything. I var_dump my `$post` before the loop and it's correct but after the reset it's still the same as the last item in the loop. Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zqYDxNDv) incase i'm doing something wrong. `wp_reset_query();` also doesn't work

Comment: try to use `get_posts();` instead `WP_Query();` or try with `global $wp_query;` before loop.